# ID Fish from Florida?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

[image]

This fish was caught in St. Augustine, Florida. What species is it?

Comment: Looks like a [Goosefish (aka. monkfish)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goosefish) to me.

Comment: Could be a species of flathead

Comment: Does it have spines?

Comment: Did you catch it in fresh water? saltwater? brackish water? And at what depth did you catch it?

Comment: Was the fish caught at the location of the photo? Approximately how deep was the water?

Answer (score 2):

Looks most likely to be a Gulf Toadfish, *Opsanus beta*, judging from its size, location caught, and other similar identifying features.

[image: Opsanus beta - photo by Ben Cantrell]
More detailed species information at:
[Opsanus beta](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/3067) on FishBase.org

Comment: I *live* in Florida and I've neither caught nor seen one of these. I was kind of taken aback!

Comment: It can depend on the environment, with this species common in bays. You would not likely catch it far off from shore.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with fish from Florida. However, that one belongs to the family Lophiidae. Most probably it is *Lophiodes reticulatus*.
Need better resolution photos for identification.

http://www.fishbase.org/summary/3082

Comment: It seems to me to only appear like a member of Lophiidae. There are other families that are similar in appearance because they are also benthic dwellers. According to FishBase, L. reticulatus is found at depths of 64-820 meters. From the photo provided you can see what appears to be an embankment along the shore. If the fish was caught at the same location, it is unlikely that the environment was of the correct depth for the fish to be L. reticulatus. There are physical features that do not match, for instance, the pectoral fins in the photo are not barbed like L. reticulatus.